# How can I show concavity of this function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I have a function of two variables:

$$r \frac{e^k-e^{rk}}{e^k-re^{rk}}.$$
Both $r$ and $k$ are positive.

How can I show that this is a concave function of $r$? I'm fairly convinced it is, but I just can't prove it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think the function looks nicer now, but feel free to edit back if you wish.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it definitely looks better. This was my first post so didn't know how to do that.

Comment: By the way, I should add that I have examined the 2nd derivative. It

Comment: Still interested?

Answer (score 0):

The concavity of $f(r)$ follows from the combination of convergence:$$\lim_{r\to+\infty} r \frac{e^k-e^{rk}}{e^k-re^{rk}} = \lim_{r\to+\infty} 1+\frac{r-1}{e^k-re^{rk}}=1$$ and monotonic increasingness: $$\frac{df}{dr}>0.$$

That is, $f\to1$ from below, and thus it must be concave.